# integrals with cauchy theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have complex analysis exam next week and one of the main question is to solve some integrals with the Cauchy formula which is $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dx$$
and I can solve a big part of the exercise that I'm asked to do but I have a problem regarding the domain.

If I have $\displaystyle \int $ in a domain like $|z|=3$, I can say whether a singularity belongs or not to the domain. However, when I have domain that do not have equations or inequalities I can not understand it.

For example if the domain is $|3e^i(^t)|$ which is if i'm not wrong a circumference with center in $2$, but does that mean that the singularity have to be inside?

Another question: if a singularity is not in the domain, what do I have to do? Cause my teacher sometimes says that "since the singularity does not belong to the domain then the integral is $0$ but sometìmes proceeds to find a similar way to express the integral and then finds an answer, should the integral be $0$ when the function is analytic?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong formula in the post. The formula should be $$f(z)=\frac1{2\pi{i}}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,\mathrm{d}w,$$ where $\gamma$ is a closed contour in $U,$ the domain of $f,$ such that the region $D$ enclosed by $\gamma$ contains $z.$ It is very important that $f$ be holomorphic in the region enclosed, for this formula to work, and it is necessary that there be no singularities in the region enclosed either. If the region does enclose singularities, then instead, $$\frac1{2\pi{i}}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,\mathrm{d}w=\sum_{m=0}^n\mathrm{I}(\gamma,c_m)\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{f(w)}{w-z},c_m\right),$$ where the $c_m$ are the singularities enclosed, and $\mathrm{I}(\gamma,c_m)$ is the corresponding winding number.

I assume, from the context of your post, is that the contour given to you is a closed curve $\gamma$ as a function from $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $\mathbb{C},$ whose graph is $\gamma(t)=2+3e^{it},$ since you said the curve was a circumference with center $2.$ The domain of $f$ is then some open set $U$ that contains this circumference, and the region enclosed by this curve, $D,$ is the region where you need to check for singularities. The specifics of $U$ do not actually matter for the purpose of your exercise, only the region $D,$ which is the region enclosed by the given $\gamma,$ matters.

Comment: then i think i misunderstood the definition of singularity, i though that a singularity iss a point where the function is not continue anymore, is it wrong? so if my exercise is $∫(1/e^z) (z+2)^3 dz$ with domain $|3e^i(^t)|$ what should i do? cause i would use the cauchy formula for derivates with $z=-2$ and $f(z)=1/e^z$ but the domain in this case does not contain -2, how should i work??

Comment: @andrea98 In the context of complex analysis, the word "singularity" refers to either a pole, or an essential singularity. You should have reviewed those concepts previously in your course, and if you have not, then I suggest you take a look at the Wikipedia article on those for reference.

Comment: @andrea98 As for the "domain," I do not know what you are saying. Are you saying your contour is equal to $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(t)=3e^{it}$? Because if you are not saying that, then I have no idea of what you are saying. Your usage of the word "domain" does not make sense in this context. In complex analysis, one does not integrate over a "domain," that is just not how that works. Integrals in complex analysis are contour integrals: they are integrals over a contour. Also, I have no idea what set of numbers $|3e^{it}|$ is supposed to refer to.

Comment: @andrea98 When you talk about $|3e^{it}|,$ are you referring to the set of numbers satisfying $|z|=3,$ or are you talking about something else? And finally, what is the integrand? Is the integrand $$\frac1{e^z}(z+2)^3$$ or $$\frac1{e^z(z+2)^3}?$$ You formatted your expression in a way that it makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @andrea98 Since you are talking about using singularities, it sounds to me like the exercise is intended to be to compute $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{e^{-z}}{(z+2)^3}\,\mathrm{d}z$$ over the cirlce given by $|z|=3.$ If so, then the interior of the circle contains a singularity at $z=-2,$ but it is a pole of order $3.$